# Linq All with a condition

Tags: linq, entity-framework

DB:

[image]

I'm trying to bring back data only when `All` of the ReviewItems meet the condition of ReviewItemStatus==3.  This works.

Problem: But then I want to narrow the scope of `All` to all ReviewItems where ReviewerID==1000

```
 // I want ALL groupAccountLinks only for ReviewerID==1000 and AccountID
// 0)  (and thus ReviewItems) for Account Charlie have ReviewItemStatusID==3
var xx = Accounts.Where(acc => acc.GroupAccountLinks.All(gal => 
                        // do ANY of the (1) associated reviewItems contain ri.ReviewItemStatusID == 3
                        gal.ReviewItems.Any(ri => ri.ReviewItemStatusID == 3)
                        // This doesn't work
                        //&& ri.Review.ReviewerID == 1000
                     )
&& acc.AccountID == 1002 // Charlie

);
```

Will be going against EF4.1   Currently testing using Linqpad and LinqToSQL test db.

Comment: Somehow even the working part you describe does not match what your query is doing. For me it reads like: Return Charlies account only if **all** of its `GroupAccountLinks` contain **at least one** `ReviewItem` in Status 3. There is no condition about *all ReviewItems*. How do you want to extend that now? Return Charlies account only if **all** of its `GroupAccountLinks` contain **at least one** `ReviewItem` in Status 3 with a ReviewerID 1000? Probably not, or yes...?

Comment: Yes - return Charlies account only if all his ReviewItems have ReviewItemStatus==3 for ReviewerID==1000.  There is only ever 1 ReviewItem per 1 GroupAccountLink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jesse, Slauma and RemeshRams which lead me to this:

```
var xxx = Accounts.Where(
        // do All Accounts satisfy condition
        u => u.Accounts.All(
                        // do All GroupAccountLinks (and thus ReviewItems) for Account meet the condition of ReviewItemStatusID==3
                        acc => acc.GroupAccountLinks.All(
                                                        // for ReviewItems where ReviewerID==1000, do they All have ReviewItemStatusID==3 
                                                        gal => gal.ReviewItems.Where(
                                                                                    ri => ri.Review.ReviewerID == 1000)
                                                                                .All(
                                                                                    ri => ri.ReviewItemStatusID == 3
                                                                                            )
                                                                // Make sure there are some ReviewItems
                                                                && gal.ReviewItems.Any()
                                                        )
                        )
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have && Condition .So, I think your table not have  all `AccountId`=1002 and All `ReviewItemStatusID` =3 . So Change && condition to || condition.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do would be to take the `&& acc.AccountID == 1002` off and make sure that you're getting the entire unfiltered set of `Accounts` that have a `ReviewItem` in status 3. If that looks good try doing your filter this way:

```
        var xx = Accounts
                  .Where(acc => acc.GroupAccountLinks
                                   .All(gal => gal.ReviewItems
                                          .Any(ri => ri.ReviewItemStatusID == 3))
                         .FirstOrDefault(acc => acc.AccountID == 1002);
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse - yes everything behaving as expected.  However the problem is still the All.. I want to narrow down the All statement to All Where ReviewerID==1000

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!